# React-native: Maximum update depth exceeded and Call arrow function as regurlar function

Tags: javascript, react-native

first, sorry for my bad English. I'm coding a function and have error: `Maximum update depth exceeded` [here is error image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8Ozga.png)

This is code cause error:
I have an arrow function that will change state value after touchable onPress

```
toggleEdit = () => {
      setTimeout(() => {
      this.setState({
          isEdit: !this.state.isEdit
      })}, 150 )
  }
```

This is Render function :

```
render() {
    return (
      <View style={styles.body}>
        <View style={styles.headerTitle}>
          <View>
            <TouchableOpacity onPress={this.buttonLeft}>
              <Icon
                name="chevron-left"
                type="evilicon"
                color="#FFFFFF"
                size={calcScale(62)}
              />
            </TouchableOpacity>
          </View>
          <View>
            <Text style={styles.titleFont}>
              {constQuotes.constQuoteAmount.label_title}
            </Text>
          </View>
          <View style={{marginLeft: 'auto', marginRight: calcScale(17)}}>
            <TouchableOpacity onPress={this.toggleEdit}>
              <Text style={styles.titleAction}>
                {!this.state.isEdit ? `Edit` : `Cancel`}
              </Text>
            </TouchableOpacity>
          </View>
        </View>
      </View>
    );
  }
```

When I call **toggleEdit** with `onPress={this.toggleEdit}`, function run ok,
But I call that with `onPress={this.toggleEdit()}`:

```
<View style={{marginLeft: 'auto', marginRight: calcScale(17)}}>
            <TouchableOpacity onPress={this.toggleEdit()}>
              <Text style={styles.titleAction}>
                {!this.state.isEdit ? `Edit` : `Cancel`}
              </Text>
            </TouchableOpacity>
          </View>
```

I have error `Maximum update depth exceeded`

What is difference between two ways ? Why did I have that error ?
Please help me, tks so much!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

EDIT: Your error is because you're creating a loop with your onPress.

> When I call toggleEdit with onPress={this.toggleEdit}, function run
>   ok, But I call that with onPress={this.toggleEdit()}:

This is a key point of how javascript works. Your first example is the correct one. It essentially says "when I press this, run the function `this.toggleEdit()`" The second example is "when I press this, run the function that `this.toggleEdit()` returns". In your particular case, `toggleEdit()` doesn't return a function; it causes an effect. And because everything within `render()` gets run any time any effect happens, the function will run forever.

As a side note: (original answer)
Remember that [state updates may be asynchronous](https://reactjs.org/docs/state-and-lifecycle.html#state-updates-may-be-asynchronous). Because you're updating state within your setState call, you need to use the function form.

```
toggleEdit = () => {
      setTimeout(() => {
      this.setState(state => {
          isEdit: !state.isEdit
      })}, 150 )
  }
```

Comment: tks so much for your explain, it's very helpful for me

Answer (score 0):

When you call `this.toggleEdit()` your call your function directly : at each render `toggleEdit` is executed, and you have a lifecycle loop, but when if you call your function without parenthesis you pass into `TouchableOpacity` props to your function so it's executed once. If it's not very clear I suggest you doc official documentation : https://reactnative.dev/docs/handling-touches.

Comment: tks for your suggestion

Answer (score 0):

replace

```js
onPress={this.toggleEdit()}
```

by

```js
onPress={()=>this.toggleEdit()}
```

Comment: or just `onPress={this.toggleEdit}`

Comment: onPress={()=>this.toggleEdit()} will run after I touch this element, is that right ?

Answer (score 0):

In second case you are calling function in-place. You are not passing a function but the value returned by it and because that function is responsibe for rendering, infinite loop occurs.

In first case you are passing that function to onPress to execute it later when event happens.